# how to deploy to vercel next js with puppeteer?

Tags: next.js, puppeteer

I want to deploy my project to vercel and I succeed, but `puppeteer` doesn't work there, because there is no executablePath. Now I've seen guides for using `chrome-aws-lambda`, but it doesn't really work for me, the versions are too old for what I use.

what can do ?

> this the code

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio'

export const searchPlayer = async (query , page) => {
    const url = `https://www.transfermarkt.com/schnellsuche/ergebnis/schnellsuche?ajax=yw0&query=${query}&Spieler_page=${page}&Trainer_page=${page}&Verein_page=${page}&Schiedsrichter_page=${page}`
    let nextPage = -1;
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: 'new',
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setCookie({
            name: 'consentUUID',
            value: 'c819fae5-8610-400f-8769-41fea1b22bda_19',
            domain: 'www.transfermarkt.com',
        });

        await page.goto(url, {
            waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded',
        });

        await page.setUserAgent(
            "5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
        );

        try {
            const paginationElement = await page.$('.tm-pagination__list-item--active + li');
            if (paginationElement) {
                const nextNumber = await page.evaluate((element) => element.textContent, paginationElement);
                nextPage = nextNumber;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            nextPage = -1;
        }

        // Wait for the desired content to be rendered on the page
        const getTable = await page.waitForXPath('/html/body/div[2]/main/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]', { timeout: 5000 }).catch(() => null);
        if (!getTable) {
            await browser.close();
            return [];
        }

        const trElements = await page.$x('/html/body/div[2]/main/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr');
        // const search = [];

        const tableRows = await Promise.all(trElements.map(async (tr) => {
            const rowData = await page.evaluate((row) => {
                const tds = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('td'));
                const data = {
                    href: tds[2]?.querySelector('a')?.href || '',
                    name: tds[2]?.textContent || '',
                    position: tds[4]?.textContent || '',
                    club: tds[3]?.textContent || '',
                    age: tds[6]?.textContent || '',
                    marketValue: tds[8]?.textContent || '',
                    agency: tds[9]?.textContent || ''
                };
                return data;
            }, tr);

            return rowData;
        }));



        await browser.close();

        return {
            "next": nextPage == "" ? "-1" : nextPage,
            "result": tableRows
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        return [];
    }
};
```

> this is my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.132",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.3",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "eslint": "8.41.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.4",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "next": "13.4.4",
    "puppeteer": "^20.5.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
```

Comment: You're mixing frontend and backend. Next is frontend. Puppeteer is backend.

Comment: Next.js is not just frontend. I haven't tried this, but it might help: https://github.com/browserless/vercel-puppeteer